# Paperclip. Handling files with identical filenames

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

If I save two files with similar filenames which will go into the same directory, one will overwrite another. How to make to work the following way, let's say, there is already picture.jpg in a directory, and if I paperclip uploads another picture.jpg into the same directory, it will automatically rename it to picture-1.jpg and so on. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can [randomize](http://trevorturk.com/2009/03/22/randomize-filename-in-paperclip/) the filenames if you like.

Answer (score 2):

Configure the attachment to include the primary ID of the record to ensure there can't be duplicates... something like this:

```
:path => ':rails_root/public/system/assets/photos/:id/:style.:extension',
:url =>                    '/system/assets/photos/:id/:style.:extension'
```

To be clear... the above also removes the original filename, but there's an expansion keyword to get that back in as well... I just never use it.

Comment: I use :id/:style/:basename.:extension to keep the original filename